# How does Starbucks wifi / etc "hijack" your internet connection?

Tags: linux, router, dns, ip, resolv.conf

I don't have a strong knowledge of DNS, but I do have a little bit, like I've done `apropos dns` and flicked through some of the mentioned `man` pages.

When I sign onto what I'll call "corporate-free" wifi, `wicd-curses` tells me an IP (sometimes a "local" `10.x.x.x` IP, sometimes loopback, sometimes a normal-looking IP) that I've connected to like a normal router would.

When I look at `/etc/resolv.conf` I can see something has overwritten my normal one. The `nameserver` might be redirected to something unusual, and there's a `search` parameter that wants to send me to like a "wayport".

What is going on under the hood here? (Not too deep under the hood, please.) The level I would like to get to is, if for whatever reason the "wayport" doesn't play happy with linux, I'd like to be able to do something like edit `resolv.conf` to get myself to their agreement page.

Comment: All that happens is you get a DNS server like you do with any DHCP connection, ant that DNS server gives the same reply to any query, taking you to the login page of the wifi service.  Once authenticated, it will serve proper answers to DHCP requests.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to find odd many things that are actually quite normal. An `10.x.x.x` address *is* very much a normal-looking one – it has everything that an IPv4 address should have (four dot-separated octets). It's just specifically assigned by RFC 1918 for LAN use, alongside 192.168.x.x.

Likewise, having /etc/resolv.conf overwritten is also normal – as part of the network connection process, wicd obtains your IP address *and* the network's recommended DNS servers from DHCP.

That said. Captive portals work in several ways:

- Some intercept all DNS traffic and send you fake DNS replies pointing to the portal webserver. (This happens *regardless* of what DNS servers you're trying to use, so trying to ignore the DHCP-provided info is pointless.)
- Other kinds intercept HTTP and HTTPS traffic directly, and reply to all requests with HTTP 302 redirects to the same portal.

Once you log in and/or click the "accept ToS" button, the portal website adjusts firewall rules on the router to remove the interception and let you browse as usual.

---

The resolv.conf `search` parameter is also obtained from DHCP, but it doesn't mean anything here. It just means "append this domain *if none was given*".

For example, if you connect to Example Corp's office network and try to access `http://mail/` (with no domain name), then the system will try `http://mail.example.com/` first, because your system has obtained `search example.com` from the office network.

This functionality is practically *never* used in public hotspots, but often the DHCP server will send whatever domain according to its own internal hostname, just because it's the default mode. So if you see `search guest.example.com`, that probably merely means the DHCP server was named `dhcp-nyc42.guest.example.com` or such.

Comment: It's more the search and nameserver fields wayports choose that confuse me. I don't think I said 10.x.x.x or rewriting resolv.conf was weird.

Comment: Oh I see what you were looking at. By "normal IP" I meant out in the wild blue internet, not local.

Comment: Do the captive portals remember your MAC address to identify who can go through the firewall? Or…?

Comment: Usually they do, though it can vary (e.g. the captive portal feature in pfSense has options to track just the IP, or just the MAC).